# how does batch size work in TimeDistributed

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm beginner of AI and trying to implement the CRNN model in Keras.

`model.add(TimeDistributed(base_model, input_shape=(3,32,32,3)))`

I understand that the above code creates 3 timesteps and uses a 32x32 RGB image.

Then, if I have 90 train_image and set batch size to 30, how does it work?

[grouped 30 pieces and entered into the timestep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li5p6.png)

or

[enter into timestep in order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XAf2.png)

or am I misunderstanding about batch size?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 90 images and you want a batch size of 30, then your input_shape should be  (90,30,32,32,3). Source: the docs https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/time_distributed/

Batch size is the amount of samples you want to use in an iteration of learning, before your CRNN updates its internal parameters.

As you can see in your screenshots you’ve trained your model for one epoch, in 3 timesteps (when training your learning model, an epoch is one iteration through the entire dataset.  30 times 3 makes 90, the whole dataset).